# Seifert manifolds

Tags: manifolds, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Seifert fiber space is a PFB. The theorem states that every principal fiber bundle (PFB) admits a connection form, so how can we define the connection 1-form on it? Or how can I find a book or article about the subject?

Comment: Do you want an Ehresmann connection for general fiber bundles?

Comment: yes...pls..     i will be glad..thnkss

Comment: Try Kobayashi and Nozumi's Differential Geometry, or Morita's "Geometry of Differential Forms; look up "Ehresmann Connection" in the index.

Comment: i have nozumi..part 1  wiill look foor that...thnjks ..